# Why would a valid call to glob in Node sometimes fail silently?

Tags: javascript, node.js, glob

The code in question looks like this:

```
glob("./bin/Documentation/images/*.gif", {}, async function (er, files) {
    if (er)
        return console.error(er)
    for (filename of files) {
        execFileSync(gifsicle, ['-O2', '-o', filename, filename]);
    }
```

This is valid production code, or at least it was until this started to happen. Tracing in the debugger shows that it builds the file list but then fails silently, perhaps while unwinding the promise. No error, no exceptions, nothing to go on. It just never enters the callback and just exits.

The version is glob@9 due to breaking changes in later versions.

Obviously I would like to solve the problem and get it working, but underlying this is a serious question as to how something as widely used as glob can fail silently, and no-one seems to have written about it. And how to debug it when it happens.

Full code available if anyone wants it. https://github.com/increpare/PuzzleScript/blob/master/compile.js

---

I understand absolutely the desire for a small repro case, but the only way I know to reproduce this is to go the full Monty.

- Clone the https://github.com/increpare/PuzzleScript repo.
- `npm i rimraf@3 compress-images web-resource-inliner ncp gifsicle@5.3.0 concat ycssmin terser gzipper html-minifier-terser glob@9`
- `node ./compile.js`

Which is why I was hoping someone else already knows the problem, and the solution.

Comment: What do I have to do to reproduce this?

Comment: It is best to have a [mre] in the post itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you're running was written for an earlier version of `glob` that supported callback-based function calls. In version 9, `glob` was rewritten (see the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/blob/main/changelog.md#90)) so that it only supports an async version that returns promises or a sync version that returns the list of files directly.

So it's not that it's failing silently, you're just calling a function that returns a promise but never awaiting the promise. The callback you're passing as the third argument never gets called.

So your options are to roll back to an earlier version of `glob` (I suspect `glob` 8 is compatible, and the repository should add a `package.json` and `package-lock.json` to pin to the versions that do work), or to update the code to use the new `async` function calls. That would look something like changing:

```
glob("./bin/Documentation/images/*.gif", {}, async function (er, files) {
  // ...
}
```

to

```
const files = await glob("./bin/Documentation/images/*.gif", {})
// ...
```

Although you'd probably also want to check if version 9 of `glob` introduced any other changes that would affect the behaviour of the code.